# Approximate Nearest Neighbors in Mathematica?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, searching, data-science

Is there any support for [Approximate Nearest Neighbors](https://medium.com/@kevin_yang/simple-approximate-nearest-neighbors-in-python-with-annoy-and-lmdb-e8a701baf905) (ANN) in Mathematica or third-party packages? I'm looking for a good implementation of [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#LSH_algorithm_for_nearest_neighbor_search) for applications where `Nearest` is not efficient enough.

Currently, v11.3 seems to only support three exact KNN methods "Octree", "KDtree", and "Scan".

Comment: It would be helpful to have an explicit small example of input and plausible output.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok, would a description of how the algorithm works with like steps and dummy variables suffice?

Comment: Yes, that would be good (especially if the description is or contains a small example).